# Cypress - how to send parameters to same function inside it's callback

Tags: javascript, api, testing, cypress

I'm trying to implement fixtures in my cypress project to avoid repeatedly sending same requests.

Command "ReadFixture" returns data from fixture file:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("ReadFixture", (fixtureName, firstKey, secondKey = "") => {
  let fixturePath = `cypress/fixtures/${fixtureName}.json`;

  if (secondKey.length === 0) {
    cy.readFile(fixturePath).then(fixture => {
      let dataArray = [];
      let fixtureKeys = Object.keys(fixture);
      fixtureKeys.forEach(key => {
        let data = fixture[key][firstKey];
        dataArray.push(data);
      });
      return cy.wrap(dataArray);
    });
  }

  else {
    cy.readFile(fixturePath).then(fixture => {
      let dataArray = fixture[secondKey][firstKey];
    });
    return cy.wrap(dataArray);
  };
});
```

Data is in json structure:

```
{
  "id_0": {
    "id": "id_0",
    "more_data": [
      "string_0"
    ]
  },
  "id_1": {
    "id": "id_1",
    "more_data": [
      "string_1",
      "string_2"
    ]
  }
}
```

For some tests, only "id" is required, such test example:

```
it("Level 1", () => {
        cy.ReadFixture("fixture_name", "id").then(urlKeys => {
            urlKeys.forEach(keyUrl => {
                cy.request({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: `${reqUrl}/${keyUrl}`
                }).then(response => {
                    expect(response.status).to.be.equal(200);
                });
            });
        });
    })
```

Everything works as expected, however, for other tests "more_data" of single "id" is required. My approach is to read fixture twice - first get array of "id", like in "Level 1" test, then get "more_data" for each "id" in array. Example:

```
it("Level 2", () => {
    cy.ReadFixture("fixture_name", "id").then(urlKeys => {
        urlKeys.forEach(keyUrl => {
            cy.ReadFixture("fixture_name", "more_data", keyUrl).then(keyData => {
                cy.request({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: `${reqUrl}/${keyUrl}/more_data`
                }).then(response => {
                    expect(response.status).to.be.equal(200);
                    expect(response.body.more_data).to.be.eql(keyData);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Problem is, when

```
cy.ReadFixture("fixture_name", "more_data", keyUrl)
```

is called, keyUrl is not defined for it and command returns array of "more_data" from all "id" because of if statement. Also, keyUrl can't be passed to request. Is it possible to go around this issue or the method I'm using is completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your else block to `wrap` the values inside your `then` callback:

```
 else {
    cy.readFile(fixturePath).then(fixture => {
      let dataArray = fixture[secondKey][firstKey];
      return cy.wrap(dataArray);
    });
 };
```